# Check if one number is within one percentage of another number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 numbers.

```
a = 134
b = 165
```

I want to find out by what percentage number a is less than number b. My aim is to find if first number (a) is within 1% of second number (b).
I created function as follow

```
def is_what_percent_of(num_a, num_b):
    return (num_a / num_b) * 100
```

But it doesnt give me what I want. I want to check if given number (a) is within 1% of other number(b).

example

```
a = 99.3
b = 100


In this case, number a falls within 1% of number b and this it should return True.
```

Is there any easy way for this?

Comment: `0.99 * b<a< 1.01 * b` ?

Comment: What does mean *is within 1% of* ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Please check second example, 1% of b is one. Number a is within 1% of number b.

Comment: @HMH1013 I should try it

Comment: `0.99 * b<a< 1.01 * b` This is just for `a`and `b`are positive, if  `a`and `b`are negative need to be changed to `1.01 * b<a< 0.99 * b`

Comment: @HMH1013 0.99 will be 0.1% or 1 %? What is I have to change it to 0.5%? How can I write for 0.5%?

Comment: Here is the percentage : `((b -a ) / b)  *100` with your example `a = 99.3` and `b = 100`, result is `0.7%`.

Comment: `99 < is_what_percent_of(a, b) < 101`

Comment: Or more generally, `100 - delta < is_what_percent_of(a, b) < 100 + delta` where `delta` is the percentage you want `a` to be within range of `b` (e.g. 1, 0.1, 0.5 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the percentage corresponding to the difference between a and b in absolute value and compare it to 1%:

```
if abs(a-b)/b <= 0.01 :
    ...
```

If you need it to work both ways (i.e. any of the two numbers is within 1% of the other), take the largest of the two as denominator:

```
if abs(a-b)/max(a,b) <= 0.01 :
    ...
```